# AIMA Framework printing states

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence

Considering that AIMA has functions to return the actions/instrumentation followed for a given problem, is there a way to get a list of expanded nodes, or the states which led to the problem's solution? I've scoured the source code and couldn't find much. If anyone has worked with this framework in the past and feels like helping, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Clarification: AIMA means the textbook *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach*.)

In aima-python, the Node class has a path() method returning the path to reach it from the initial state. Probably aima-java, etc., have something similar.